# Migrating Angular http calls to v6

Tags: angular

I'm trying to do a http get to retrieve a boolean value from an api, and running into problems with Angular 6 (the code works in v5):

My userservice.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})


export class UserService {

    readonly baseUrl = `${environment.apiUrl}/user`;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    public isAdmin(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.http.get<boolean>(this.baseUrl + '/isAdmin');
    }

}
```

My component:

```
export class TestComponent{
  public admin: boolean;

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {
    this.userService.isAdmin()
      .subscribe(
        result => {
          this.admin = result;
        }
      );

  }
}
```

The error that I'm getting in the console when I navigate to my component is this.userService.isAdmin is not a function

Comment: Have you migrated to RxJS 6 and/or installed the compatibility module per https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md? I think you should have `import { Observable } from 'rxjs';` now.

Comment: You're right @jonrsharpe , changing my import fixed it.  Thanks!